# Rough edged text after applying Otsu's threshold for text extraction

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, text-extraction

I am trying to separate text from background by using Otsu's threshold mechanism. Even though the algorithm separates text from background, the resultant text has rough edges, which in turn decreases the accuracy of text recognition.

The input image and the output image after applying threshold are given below:

[image: Text image] 
[image: Image after applying threshold]

What can I do to remove just the background? I want to retain the text as it is in the original image with clear-cut edges and no breaks or thinning.

Comment: Please read [ask]... "Can anybody help please?" is not a very good question. What is it you want to know?
The output is exactly what you would  expect from applying Otsu. Binarized images always look a bit rough as you don't have any gradient edge transitions anymore...

Comment: You could try local region threshold techniques like Niblack threshold, Sauvola threshold or even Feng's method. They focus on region based threshold

Comment: You can also try local histogram equalization before trying the above mentioned steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get better results using a local threshold operation instead of a global one like Otsu.

But you should not expect too much.  Smooth looking edges are the result of gradient transitions between forground and background. You will most likely have pixels of the same value that you would consider foreground and others you would consider background in the same character...

If you want better results you should improve the quality of your input image.